# Selenium Selecionar Botao

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Olá,executando meu código em python não conseguir Selecionar um botão

HTML:

```
<div class="pushpad_deny_button" style="position: relative;top:0;right:0;display: inline-block;float: left;width: 100px;margin-right: 6px;text-align: center;padding: 12px;text-align: center;font-weight: normal;font-size: 13px;color: #0670c3; cursor: pointer;">ALLOW</div>
```

Meu Código:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser =webdriver.Chrome(r'')
al=browser.find_element_by_link_text('ALLOW')
al.click()
```

Erro:`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector"`

Oque estou Fazendo ERRADO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A página não está carregada, o script não espera sozinho a página ter sido baixada e renderizada, ou seja o DOM provavelmente não está pronto

Para isto você pode aplicar um tempo de espera razoável de 10 a 30 segundos de limite, para esperar o DOM processar, um exemplo de forma forma **implícita**:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'')
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Se dez segundos não for o bastante use 20:

```
browser.implicitly_wait(20)
```

Se não use 30:

```
browser.implicitly_wait(30)
```

---

Ou usar a forma **explícita**, para isto adicione isto no topo do script:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

E troque:

```
al=browser.find_element_by_link_text('ALLOW')
```

Por (usando XPath):

```
al = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "ALLOW"]'))
)
```

Se dez segundos não for o bastante use 20:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
```

Se não use 30:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
```

Só deve usar mais que isto se tiver certeza que a página solicitada é lenta mesmo.

---

### Checando se o elemento é clicável

Note que mesmo que o elemento exista e esteja pronto pode ser que ao usar o `click()` ele seja "não clicável" e irá ocasionar alguns problemas como:

- `ElementNotVisibleException`
- `ElementNotSelectableException`

Dependendo da situação, como oculto, então em botões e links ao invés de `EC.presence_of_element_located` use `EC.element_to_be_clickable`, assim:

```
al = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() != "ALLOW"]'))
)
```

Vale notar que para outros tipos de elementos você pode aplicar outras condições (`EC`):

- `EC.title_is`
- `EC.title_contains`
- `EC.visibility_of_element_located`
- `EC.visibility_of`
- `EC.presence_of_all_elements_located`
- `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element`
- `EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value`
- `EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`
- `EC.invisibility_of_element_located`
- `EC.staleness_of`
- `EC.element_to_be_selected`
- `EC.element_located_to_be_selected`
- `EC.element_selection_state_to_be`
- `EC.element_located_selection_state_to_be`
- `EC.alert_is_present`

---

### Não use `sleep()`

Não é que não deva, a não ser que seja de interesse do script de fato usar, mas para DOM dentro do Selenium o ideal é usar o 
`WebDriverWait`, isto porque ele procura o elemento a todo momento até que o limite (10, 20, 30, etc) termine, ou seja se encontrar antes do tempo limite ele não vai precisar continuar, ele vai processar antes e não vai ficar travado até o tempo acabar

Comment: Erro:AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions' has no attribute 'find_element_by_link_text'

Comment: @Pakito qual versão do Selenium? ps: usei este mesmo código aqui e funcionou, se não ser use o implicity_wait ... **NÃO USE O `sleep()`**, ele não "checa" se o DOM está pronto, vai travar tudo, o `implicitly_wait`, A GRANDE vantagem do implicitly_wait e do WebDriverWait é que pesquisam no DOM até o tempo acabar, ou seja se o elemento for achado antes do tempo limite ele vai prosseguir sem precisar terminar o tempo, ao contrário do sleep que só trava tudo e vai ser obrigado a esperar acabar o tempo todo.

Comment: Deu outro erro:EC.presence_of_element_located((by.XPATH, '//*[text() != "ALLOW"]'))
NameError: name 'by' is not defined

Comment: @Pakito importe o `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`, desculpe, são muitas classes as vezes acabo esquecendo de mencionar: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By. Editei a resposta

Comment: não precisar por al.click() ? na 2 opçao?

Comment: Caro @Pakito nunca disse isso, eu resolvi a parte que estava do seu código, a parte de "buscar o elemento", o que você vai fazer com ele, clicar, remover, mover, é de seu interesse... ps: o `element_to_be_clickable` "verifica se é clicável", como descrito em destaque, não clica, apenas verifica se é "possível", então você executa o clique depois o que desejar, nos exemplos resolvi a parte com problema.

Comment: So que no problema estava a variavel al.click()

Comment: @Pakito por que? Não está correto `al=` aqui: `al = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(...`?

Comment: Não e isso Por quando pois essa variável tinha também o objectivo de fazer o click por isso achei que estava claro!

Comment: Mas Poder Ajudar?

Comment: @Pakito não entendi, aonde exatamente está falhando? Chegou a fazer isto `al = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() != "ALLOW"]'))
) al.click()`?

Comment: No Codigo que Atualizei so queriar conseguir Clickar nessa Caixa.

Answer (score -1):

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep 

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'').sleep(0.5)
al = browser.find_element_by_link_text('ALLOW')
al.click()
```

Segue uma possível solução.

Comment: Soluçâo: al = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[text() = "NO THANKS"]')) )
al.click() resolveu!