# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //div[@class='classificacao_pontos-corridos']//table

Tags: html5, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Olá,

fiz um webscraping com python no mozila e funcionou. Entretanto, quando tentei aplicar o código em outro site, estou recebendo a mensagem de erro do título.

Na prática:

1. Ao rodar o programa o mozila é aberto e se passa 10s do comando `time.sleep(10)`
2. Em seguida aparece o erro no promt para a linha:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='classificacao_pontos-corridos']//table//thead//tr//th[@class='tabela_head--coluna']").click
```

3. Ao tentar remover essa parte do cógigo o mesmo erro passa para a linha:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='classificacao_pontos-corridos']//table")
```

código:

```
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path=r'C:\geckodriver-v0.28.0-win64 
(1)\\geckodriver.exe')

url = "https://globoesporte.globo.com/futebol/brasileirao-serie-a/"

driver.get(url)   

time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='classificacao_pontos- 
corridos']//table//thead//tr//th[@class='tabela_head--coluna']").click

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='classificacao_pontos-corridos']//table")

html_content = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Comment: Olá Leonardo, talvez o `DIV` esta dentro de um iframe ou o elemento ainda não existe, experimente WebDriverWait: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/425211/3635